# Create UTF-8 file using HttpServletResponse

Tags: servlets, utf-8, character-encoding, outputstream

I am trying to create a UTF-8 file "myFile.aaa" using HttpServletResponse (HttpServlet). The reason why I need this to be UTF-8 is because it might contain special non-printable characters.

However, code below seems to create ANSI-encoded file. At least that is what Notepad++ says, and what I can see reading chars from this file. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; charset=UTF-8");
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=myFile.aaa");
        res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
        os.print("Hello World");
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to specify `charset` on an `octet-stream`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to use the character writer of the response, not the byte output stream.

Replace

```
ServletOutputStream os = res.getOutputStream();
os.print("Hello World");
os.flush();
os.close();
```

by

```
res.getWriter().write("Some UTF-8");
```

Further, I'd recommend setting content type to `text/plain`, not to an overly generic one which implies binary content, not character content.

I'm not sure about Notepad++, but in Notepad, if the text document does not contain any characters beyond the ANSI range, it will be interpreted as ANSI. Don't mislead you by this behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my sample:

```
private static final String KALIMAH = "\u0644\u064e\u0622 \u0625\u0650\u0644\u0670\u0647\u064e \u0625\u0650\u0644\u0651\u064e\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647\u064f \u0645\u064f\u062d\u064e\u0645\u0651\u064e\u062f\u064c \u0631\u0651\u064e\u0633\u064f\u0648\u0652\u0644\u064f \u0627\u0644\u0644\u0647\u0650";

protected void printGreeting (HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    res.setContentType( "text/html" );
    res.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    out.write( KALIMAH );
    out.close();
}
```